# compare values of two table with several dates in one table

Tags: mysql

I have two table

employee

```
+=======+==========+
|id     |level     |
+=======+==========+
|1      |1         |
|2      |2         |
+=======+==========+
```

emp_level

```
+=======+========+==========+
|emp_id |level   |date      |
+=======+========+==========+
|1      |2       |2016-08-01|
|1      |1       |2012-08-01|
|2      |2       |2012-08-01|
+=======+========+==========+
```

I want to see if the level from `employee` matched with `emp_level` in recent date, so kinda like this

```
+=================+===============+===============+
|emp_level.emp_id |employee.level |emp_level.level|
+=================+===============+===============+
|1                |1              |2              |
|2                |2              |2              |
+=================+===============+===============+
```

I've tried `UNION` but the result from second table is on different row, and I don't know how to do it for all emp_id. my query:

```
(select id, level from employee where id="957")
union all
(select emp_id as id, level from emp_level where 
           emp_id= "957" order by date desc limit 1)
```

Comment: It's still unclear. Please add valid sample input and show your expected output based on that.

Comment: @1000111 there's no input, just compare all row in those two table. and my expected output is already on question

Comment: I see there's no entry for `emp_id=2` in `emp_level` table. But there's a row for `emp_id=2` in your expected output. Explain this please.

Comment: @1000111 added on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT 
E.id,
E.level,
maxDateLevelTable.level
FROM employee E 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    EL.*
    FROM emp_level EL
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        emp_id,
        MAX(date) max_date
        FROM emp_level
        GROUP BY emp_id
    ) AS t
    ON t.emp_id = EL.emp_id AND t.max_date= EL.date
) AS maxDateLevelTable

ON E.id = maxDateLevelTable.emp_id
ORDER BY E.id;
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c91ae/2/0)</kbd>

**Note:** You can replace the `LEFT JOIN` by `INNER JOIN` if there's always an entry found for each employee in `emp_level` table.

**Explanation:**

If you run this query alone

```
    SELECT 
     EL.*
    FROM emp_level EL
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        emp_id,
        MAX(date) max_date
        FROM emp_level
        GROUP BY emp_id
    ) AS t
    ON t.emp_id = EL.emp_id AND t.max_date= EL.date
```

then you will get each employee's most recent data from `emp_level` table.

Later make an `inner join` between the result of this above query and `employee` table in order to get the corresponding level from `employee` table.